# Facebook share image or favicon not showing from GAE app redirected link

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, favicon

I have a website hosted on GAE but I use my own domain name have it redirect to my-app.appspot.com. When I facebook share this link, I can't see any image associated with it but when I use share the direct my-app.appspot.com link it works fine..

Same thing with the favicon, the small icon on the tab in the browser doesn't show when I use the link the redirects to my app!

Comment: What does  [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)say about the URL you're sharing? are the meta tags correctly detected?

Comment: I haven't seen this, let me try using it.

Comment: the only meta tags correctly detected are the og title, url, and description. but there's a meta for og:image in my html page... How can I can get fb to read it?

Comment: When you manually access the page (via curl for example) is the image tag returned? maybe your code just isn't returning the meta tags

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by image tags and curl, i will investigate this further..

Comment: i meant the `og:image` meta tag - this should contain the absolute URL of an image which facebook can retrieve, is 200x200 or greater (i think the absolute minimum is 50x50) and has less than 3:1 aspect ratio

Comment: No, there is no og:image tag when I manually visit the page. There's there are no other og tags, i'm not sure how facebook got the other ones. There is an og:image i put in my html source... but the redirect link only shows an iframe of my source code (aka the .appspot.com url) ... this weird and my client isn't too happy

Comment: Well only you know how your code works and why it might not be outputting the meta tags correctly - without seeing how you're generating them there's no way for anyone here to help

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in one ;-)

The favicon issue is related to caching in the browser.
If you see the favicon on one page myapp.appspot.com and not on www.example.com which redirect to myapp.appspot.com, it is also a problem with cachine
Of course, you can clear your browser's cache (see preferences/options menu)
but a sure way is to open the same page with another browser.

Share button
Look at what facebook see at
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
enter your domain

This information is fetched once every 7 days (i.e if you correct your html correctly you will have to force the open graph to update)

For the correct info to appear in the facebook debug tool, you need to 
1/ configure your button
2/ enter the open graph tags in the header.

Because you are redirecting your www.example.com domain to your appspot website, if you look at the html you will see that your appspot is included in a  html tag. In other words, the html header are NOT the one from your GAE template, but rather from the redirect wrapper.

To make all of this work, use the appspot URL in the FB button code and the open graph tags.
http://developers.connect.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
The Open graph tags represents only the content of your FB object.
The code of your FB button is key to query the open graph.
The 2 URLs must be the same! (well, the same until you fully understand how to populate AND query the open graph !)